# Notation for Alternating Temporal Logic

Tags: logic, notation

I am reading the [original paper](https://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1104&context=cis_reports) on ATL. Some of the notation is unreadable to me. In the section 3.2 on ATL Semantics, they describe a strategy for an agent $a$ as a function $f_a: Q^+ \rightarrow 2^Q$ such that forall $\lambda \in Q^*$, forall $q \in Q$, we have $f_a(\lambda \cdot q) \in \delta(q, a)$. I have questions:

1. $Q$ is just a set of states so what are $Q^+$ and $Q^*$?
2. What is the operation $\cdot: Q^* \times Q \rightarrow Q^+$ appearing in $\lambda \cdot q$?

Since they go on to say that $\lambda \cdot q$ is a finite prefix, my guess is that $\lambda \in Q^*$ is a finite sequence of states and $\lambda \cdot q$ is appending $q$ to $\lambda$, but the result will also be a finite sequence of states, so this would not explain a difference between $Q^+$ and $Q^*$.

Comment: $Q^*$ consists of all finite sequences formed by elements from $Q$, including the empty sequence, while $Q^+$ excludes the empty sequence. These notations are quite common in Computer Science.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense